# what is the diference over org.javafxports » jfxmobile-plugin 1.3.16 and 2.0.30

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

what is the diference over  org.javafxports  jfxmobile-plugin  1.3.16 and 2.0.30
I try update the version 1.3.16 to  2.0.30 but not compile project

Answer (score 1):

The jfxmobile-plugin is a gradle plugin that unifies the building of Java and JavaFX applications for different target platforms:

- desktop
- android
- ios
- embedded

JFXMobile plugin comes in two flavors:

**jfxmobile 1.3.16**

See [Maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.javafxports/jfxmobile-plugin/1.3.16/jar), and its [repository](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/).

Samples: See Gluon Mobile [samples](https://gluonhq.com/developers/samples/)

A typical build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
}
```

**jfxmobile 2.0.30**

See [Maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.javafxports/jfxmobile-plugin/2.0.30/jar), and its [repository](https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin).

Samples for Gluon VM: See Gluon Mobile with Gluon VM [samples](https://gluonhq.com/developers/samples/).

A typical build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:2.0.30'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0-jdk9'
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
}
```

**Differences**

As you can see in the [readme](https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/blob/master/README.md) for plugin 2.x:

> javafxmobile-plugin version 1.x brought Java 8 to mobile development. Version 2.x is an upgrade of the plugin that enables Java 9 development by leveraging Gluon VM.

And:

> Gluon VM is still in active development and is at the moment only supported on iOS devices.

Currently it is under developer preview.

**Summary**

If you want to develop an application for production, use the stable 1.x version, with Java 8, for both Android and iOS, where most of the Java 7 SE APIs are available, and a few Java 8 APIs are supported as well (like lambdas). Streams are not supported though.

If you want to experiment with Java 9 features, use the new 2.x version. It supports Streams, and Java 9. Note that on Android Java 9 APIs are not supported and it has to be compatible with Java 8.

Comment: Le agradezco mucho darse su tiempo en contestarme Me a quedado muy claro