# Need details for creating new Gluon-Mobile Project and differences?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

1. Single View Project
2. Single View Project on Gluon VM
3. Multi View Project
4. Multi view project with Fxml
5. Multi view project with Glisten Afterburner

Which is better for multi language?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Gluon plugin for your IDE is documented [here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.2/#_getting_started).

There are several templates available to create a Gluon Mobile project with a few classes and resources.

The differences between each of them are:

- Single View or Multi View: Gluon Mobile uses `View` [containers](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.2/#_the_views) for each of the mobile app views. The template will create just one on a Single View project (for a simple case), or two on a Multiple View project (but extensible to any number of views). The latter will be the most common case of usual apps.
- With or Without FXML: This is self-explanatory, you can select the template to use FXML (Scene Builder) or not.
- With FXML and Glisten Afterburner. This is a particular use case of FXML based on the well-known Afterburner MVP [framework](https://github.com/AdamBien/afterburner.fx) that allows Dependency Injection, customized to work with Gluon Mobile views.
- With or Without Gluon VM. The templates are defined for the JFXmobile plugin version 1.3.16+, except for one that allows Gluon VM using the plugin 2.0.30+. The differences are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889358/what-is-the-diference-over-org-javafxports-jfxmobile-plugin-1-3-16-and-2-0-30).

To get started, I would select `Multi view project with Fxml`, with Java 8, FXML (Afterburner is optional), and you can have i18n support using resource bundles, like in a regular JavaFX project.